# remove xAxis label of vertical crosshair in highchart highstock

Tags: highcharts, label, x-axis

i have a highstock chart with multiple series, each one has it's own tooltip(shared:false), after hovering mouse, a label appear on xAxis, how to get ride of it?

```
 {
       xAxis: {
           crosshair: false
        },
        tooltip: {
          useHTML: true,
          shadow: false,
          borderRadius: 0,
          borderColor: "transparent",
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          borderWidth: 0,
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            turboThreshold: 0,
          },
          states: {
            hover: {
              enabled: false,
            },
          },
        },
        series: [      {
    type: "line",
    name: series[0].name,
    data: [...],
    color: series[0].color,
    tooltip: {
      pointFormatter() {
        return `<span>tooltip1:xxx</span>`;
      },
    },
  },
  {
    type: "line",
    data: [...],
    name: series[1].name,
    color: series[1].color,
    pointFormatter() {
        return `<span>tooltip1:xxx</span>`;
      },
  }],
      }
```

in here i put a sample of what i mean and a picture:
[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kingofday/n8yLo21u/5/)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Highcharts API:

> **split: boolean** Since 5.0.0
>
> Split the tooltip into one label per series, with the header close to
> the axis. This is recommended over shared tooltips for charts with
> multiple line series, generally making them easier to read. This
> option takes precedence over tooltip.shared.

To get rid of the header set `headerFormat` to an empty string.

```
tooltip: {
  headerFormat: ''
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bc467dmo/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.headerFormat

Comment: thank you, by the way, is there any way to customize it like tooltip html?

Comment: Hi @kingofday, I am not sure what you mean, could you explain the problem more precisely?

Comment: i mean can i customize xAxis label that we get rid off with some html like tooltip instead of removing it? the reason i want to remove it, was because of its styling

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, you can use `tooltip.formatter` for that, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s3w7rm0n/

Comment: now i get it, the point was the first one is for xAxis and others for series, god bless you